# Java SWT Draw a Plan

Tags: java, user-interface, canvas, swt, draw

I'm programming my first java App, I wanna create a GUI, which allow to draw different Plan. As close as possible to this representation :

[image]

My implementation is based on SWT.

For drawing Nodes and Edges, I used `addPaintListener()` method from the class Canvas.

But i have following problem, the method `paintControl()` is called infinitely times, redrawing every time.
 I ask myself if there is a way to avoid it, or maybe a better way to draw a plan in Java.

Can someone of you suggest me a best way to draw diagram and edge in Java

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(composite, SWT.ALL);
    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {

            Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(0, 0, 60, 30);
            e.gc.drawRectangle(rect);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is normal for the painter listener to be called whenever something changes that requires repainting, this shouldn't be a problem. Note that `SWT.ALL` is not a valid style for `Canvas`

Comment: Thank you for suggestion,my program was slow a due to a wrong while loop. I thought , the problem was the continual recall of the PaintControll(). Can someone of you suggest me a best way to draw diagram and edge in Java

Answer (score 0):

i'm searching for a best implementation for my Gui-application.i have a problem in drawing edges

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22142391)

Comment: I need any suggestion,if there is a best way to draw diagram and edge in Java